# Why I can not retrieve Case.RecordTypeId as custom field in package.xml in VScode?

Tags: salesforcedx, case, record-type, helptext, metadata-relationship

I am trying to understand where i can find/locate the help text added for Case.RecordtypeId field on case in my package(VScode).
I am trying to retrieve it with record type and object, but I can not locate the inline help text for RecordTypeId which is shown in UI.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Package xmlns="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata">
    <types>
        <members>Case.RecordTypeId</members>
        <name>CustomField</name>
    </types>
    <types>
        <members>Case</members>
        <name>CustomObject</name>
    </types>
    <types>
       <members>Case.**RecordTypes**</members>
       <name>RecordType</name>
    </types>
    <version>57.0</version></Package>
```

Comment: and why can't you just retrieve `Case` as CustomObject and parse the XML within that will contain the "help text" in the `<description>` tag?

Comment: Do you mean the Description of the Record Type?